# jquery complex selector class+attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to find element with class MyClass1 that's have attribute number. My attempt was:

```
 $(".MyClass1[number=" + userId + "]")
```

but it didn't work. Where is my mistake?

```
 <tr class = "Myclass2">
    <td>
     <a href="#" number="5" title="checkselector" class="MyClass1">blablabla=)</a>           
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you're trying to select from?

Comment: Are you sure `userId` has the correct value? What you have should work. Maybe share some more code?

Comment: `number="userId"` Uhm?

Comment: oh sorry @userId its asp.net

Comment: @AntonKozlovsky: Post the **HTML** you're matching. `number="@userid"` isn't HTML, it's ASP. Is it actually a number? E.g., `number="42"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two aspects to this:

1. **What** you're matching

   If you just want to know it has an attribute, not set to a specific value, leave off the `=` and value:

   ```
   $(".MyClass1[number]")
   ```

   That will match any element with a `number` attribute and the class `MyClass1` that exists when that line of code runs.

   From your edits, it sounds like you're trying to match a specific number. Assuming `userId` contains `12`:

   ```
   var userId = 12;
   ```

   ...then your code is fine:

   ```
   $(".MyClass1[number=" + userId + "]")
   ```

   ...because that evaluates to:

   ```
   $(".MyClass1[number=12]")
   ```

   You *can* put quotes around the value, but you only **need** to if the value contains spaces or several other non-alphanumeric characters. If you know it's a number (and so only contains digits), they're unnecessary.
2. **When** you're matching it

   Earlier I said *"That will match any element with...that exists when that line of code runs."* This is important. If the code is in a script block *above* the element, it won't find it because the element doesn't exist yet:

   ```
   <!-- Doesn't work -->
   <script>
       $(".MyClass1[number=12]").css("color", "green");
   </script>
   <!-- ... -->
   <a href="#" number="12" title="@Resources.Appoint" class="MyClass1">Joe BLoggs</a>
   ```

   But if the script is *after*, then the element exists and can be found:

   ```
   <a href="#" number="12" title="@Resources.Appoint" class="MyClass1">Joe BLoggs</a>
   <!-- Works -->
   <script>
       $(".MyClass1[number=12]").css("color", "green");
   </script>
   <!-- ... -->
   ```

   The usual recommendation is to put your scripts at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag. If you don't control where they go, though, you can use jQuery's `ready` function:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       // ...your code here...
   });
   ```

   ...which can also be shortened to:

   ```
   $(function() {
       // ...your code here...
   });
   ```

Comment: sorry for a bit incorrect question =) its a number) 5,for example

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the quotes:

```
 $(".MyClass1[number='" + userId + "']")
```

Comment: Quotes aren't required unless there are spaces or some such in the ID.